# how to get data from Firebase Cloud Firestore in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, rx-kotlin

[image]

So I have a database in Firebase Cloud Firestore that stores users and tasks. Each user has a number of fields such as name, username,etc. I want to know how to fetch each field that is associated with each user using Kotlin.

I'm trying to get all these accounts so I can display them in an activity called friends, that's why I want to collect all these accounts from the database. Here is a picture of my database to have a clear understanding of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So what are you basically trying to achieve, you want to get the `name`, `username` and so on from all users or only from a single user?

Comment: @AlexMamo all users and also one user

Comment: Are you using a model class for your user?